# sSpark structured streaming PostgreSQL updatestatebykey

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

How to update state of **OUTPUT TABLE** by Spark structured streaming computation triggered by changes in **INPUT** PostgreSQL table?

As a real life scenario USERS table has been updated by `user_id = 0002`, how to trigger Spark computation for that user only and write / update results to another table?

Comment: is it necessary to use kafka with [bottledwater](https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg/blob/master/README.md) ? or can it be achieved with spark streaming only?

Comment: At this moment Spark doesn't support event triggered streams. You could write a receiver which uses Postgres [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-notify.html).

Comment: Bottledwater is no longer actively developed. I would suggest to go for Linkedin databus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no solution out of the box you can implement it the following way.

You can use Linkedin's [Databus](https://github.com/linkedin/databus) or other similar tools which mines the databse logs and produce respective events to kafka. The tool tracks the changes in database bin logs. You can write a kafka connector to transform and filter data. You can then consume events from kafka and process them to any sink format you want.